# In R Studio I'm dealing with: Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class character

Tags: r, class, ggplot2, character

So I'm trying to create a `boxplot` out of a comma delimited `.csv`. I know it was successful with this same code in another computer. I run the code and receive a "class character error" without avail. What can I do? I have seen that perhaps checking for `is.numeric`. I really appreciate any help!
Here is the code:

```
library("ggplot2")
df <- "SedimentLoadStatisticsPerProperty.csv"

p <- ggplot(df, aes(as.factor(df$Ppa), df$MEAN)) +
  #geom_point(size=2, shape=23) +                
  geom_boxplot() +                                
  theme_bw() +                                    
  scale_x_discrete("Property Price, $/Acre") +   
  labs(y=bquote('Sediment Load, ton/'~m^2)) +     
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold",size=20),axis.text.x = element_text(size=16,angle=90,vjust=0.5)) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold",size=20),axis.text.y = element_text(size=16))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your `df` is a character vector. You need to read that file in using `read.csv` and save the result to `df`.

Answer (score 2):

Two things.

First, as @shayaa pointed out, you need to first read in the csv; your current example sets df as a string listing the location.

Change this to:

`df <- read.csv("SedimentLoadStatisticsPerProperty.csv")`

Second, within ggplot, in aes avoid using df$variable. You can refer to things by the column name directly. Change this to:

`p <- ggplot(df, aes(as.factor(Ppa), MEAN)) +`

Also, depending on your data, you probably don't need `as.factor()` around Ppa.

Comment: Thank you very much to both! I will try these recommendations.